# Pandas: str.contains using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have dataframe and I need to filter that with regex.

Dataframe:

```
                  domain                    tag1  
0         ^mail.ru/search                  Сервис   
1             go.mail.ru$              Веб-портал   
2           vk.com/audios              Социальное   
3            vk.com/video              Социальное   
4             vk.com/apps              Социальное   
5                  vk.com              Социальное   
6       ^yandex.ru/search                  Сервис   
7       ^yandex.ru/pogoda                  Сервис   
8             ^yandex.ru$              Веб-портал
```

I need to get only domain

I try to use

```
def get_domain_encoding(df):
    return df[df.domain.str.contains(r'[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+.[a-zA-Z0-9]')]
```

And it returns me

```
                   domain                    tag1  
0         ^mail.ru/search                  Сервис      
2           vk.com/audios              Социальное   
3            vk.com/video              Социальное   
4             vk.com/apps              Социальное   
5                  vk.com              Социальное   
6       ^yandex.ru/search                  Сервис   
7       ^yandex.ru/pogoda                  Сервис   
8             ^yandex.ru$              Веб-портал
```

When I change it to

```
def get_domain_encoding(df):
    return df[df.domain.str.contains(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+.[a-zA-Z0-9]$')]
```

It returns me empty dataframe.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Why are you using ranges like that? `\w`.  Also, escape your periods or it's seen as a wildcard: `\.`

Comment: As @TheIncorrigible1 mentioned, use `[\w-]` for the first set instead, use `\.` for a literal dot instead of *any character except newline (unless `s` modifier is used)*. You can use `[^\W_]` for the second set as well. `^[\w-]+\.[^\W_]$`

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
df.domain.str.extract('(\w+\.)?(\w+\.\w+)', expand=False)[1]
```

Output:

```
0      mail.ru
1      mail.ru
2       vk.com
3       vk.com
4       vk.com
5       vk.com
6    yandex.ru
7    yandex.ru
8    yandex.ru
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Modify with a little cleanup, using named groups and discarding the 'subdomain' group:

```
df.domain.str.extract('(?P<subdomain>\w+\.)?(?P<domain>\w+\.\w+)',expand=False)['domain']
```

Comment: I need only domain, not subdomain